# node--front.html

Tags: 8, theming

I'm trying to isolate the node template for just the front page of Drupal 8. In Drupal 7 I could create a template node--front.html but this doesn't seem to work in Drupal 8, what's the best way to just target nodes on the front page. If I use:

```
{% if node.isPromoted() and not node.isSticky() %}
```

it effects the node on it's single page as well.

Update: I'm using Bartik as a sub theme

Answer (score 4):

You can do the following in your .theme file:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $variables['is_front'] = \Drupal::service('path.matcher')->isFrontPage();
}
```

And then in your node--page--full.html.twig (name of twig file depending on content type and view mode) use:

```
{% if is_front %}
// frontpage stuff here
{% else %}
// other stuff here
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to use is not rely on promoted/sticky but a given view mode. node--$viewmode.html.twig is available as a default template suggestion.

By default, the view mode used on the frontpage is teaser.

You probably want to use that in other places too and not all should look like the frontpage. Drupal 8 now has a UI built-in to create view modes and corresponding display configurations for the fields. You can then select which view module should be used in each view, entity reference and when you display nodes through the API.

Coupling layout/design of nodes to view modes and not e.g. a specific view or other attribute makes them re-usable. You can have other views that display them in the same way. Or not.

Comment: I am surprised nobody up-voted this answer before. (It would mean nobody recognized this answer as correct.)

Answer (score 0):

Try with **node--promoted.html.twig**.

From D8 documentation [node.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!templates!node.html.twig/8).

> **node--promoted** : Appears on nodes promoted to the front page.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, doesn't seem to change anything unfornantly

Comment: did u clear the cache?

Comment: Hi, yes I did, does this go straight in the templates folder? I got a feeling though if this does work it won't be what I want as I have the if statement working with promoted but it then effects the node when you click the read more to get the node on it's own page which I don't want to change

Comment: There is no template suggestions for promoted, not by default. And it wouldn't change anything, it's still used on the detail page too. node-promoted in that documentation is just a default CSS class.